# BACK LARAVEL EN HOSTINGER

Tags: laravel

hice un back sencillo, estoy aprendiendo laravel

la cuestion es que hice un crud pequeño de forma local y funciona de maravilla, según lo que vi en internet, para subir el back a la nube simplemente es comprimir todos los archivos, subir el archivo comprimido y luego descomprimirlo ya en el hosting en el administrador de archivos.

La cuestion es que ingreso mi url y luego a la carpeta public y me sale este error

The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.

mas abajo me sale esto

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(    
$request = Request::capture()
)->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

y me sale exactamente el error en el capture, como dije soy nuevo en esto y no tengo absolutamente ni idea de que es lo que sucede que no arranca mi back

se supone que debe ingresar al

Route::get('/Insert',[rol::class,'create']);

y en el controller coloco un hola mundo si me da

pero si en el controller coloco

rolModels:: create(['TX_ROL'=>'Test 3','BL_ESTADO'=>true]);

ya en el modelo me genera

Trait 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\softDeletes' not found

este es mi modelo

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\softDeletes;

class rolModels extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use softDeletes;
    protected $table = 'roles';
    protected $primaryKey = 'PK_ROL';
    protected $fillable = [
        'PK_ROL',
        'TX_ROL',
        'BL_ESTADO'
    ];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function user(){
        return $this -> belongsTo('App\Models\User','PK_ROL');
    }
}
```

se supone que
agradezco su ayuda

envio una foto de como quedo el fichero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya se cual es el error, por defecto lavarel coloco
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\softDeletes;
y es con la S mayuscula